# How to get the beta badge

Tags: support, badges

The description for the **[beta](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta)** badge is: "Actively participated in the private beta."  So far, no one has earned it.  What does one need to do to get the badge?

Comment: I understand that the beta badge is awarded once the private beta ends, and that it cannot be awarded after that.  But what else is needed?  A certain number of questions and answers?  A certain number of badges?  A certain value of reputation?

Comment: The site is now in public beta and I have earned a beta badge.

Answer (score 3):

One needs public beta to begin, which should occur this week. If it doesn't begin this week, we can start posting instructions on getting into the private beta and just get around the system. (I'm mostly kidding).